# error regexp django urls

Tags: django, regex

¿Por qué Django no reconoce mi url?

mi **urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from home.views import homePageView, activateUser

urlpatterns = [
    path('',homePageView.as_view(),name='home'),
    path('activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/$', activateUser.activate, name='activate')
]
```

La url a la que acccedo:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/activate/9Eri2DOMYpwI5p8/
```

el error que muestra:

> Using the URLconf defined in cryptoassistant.urls, Django tried these
>   URL patterns, in this order:
>
> admin/ [name='home'] activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/$ [name='activate']
>   activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/$ [name='activate'] The current path,
>   activate/9Eri2DOMYpwI5p8/, didn't match any of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

He resuelto el problema utilizando **re_path**:

```
from django.urls import re_path
re_path('activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/$', activateUser.activate, name='activate')
```

Answer (score 1):

No necesitas usar **Regex** con la funcion **Path** 
reemplaza:

```
path('activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/$', activateUser.activate, name='activate')
```

por:

```
path('activate/<slug:slug>)/$', activateUser.activate, name='activate')
```

Comment: con <slug:nombre> no me funciona. Lo he solucionado con from django.urls import path, re_path 
re_path('activate/([a-zA-Z0-9]{15})/$', activateUser.activate, name='activate')